# How to copy a submodule from one repo to another?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a `git` repo `R1` with a submodule `S1`, and the latter has two branches, `master` and `localpatches`.

Let `Q` represent the source repo of the `S1` submodule (in other words, `Q` is the argument that was given to the `git submodule add ...` that initially created the `S1` submodule in `R1`).

For the purpose of this question you may assume that `S1`'s `localpatches` branch is a direct descendant of its `master` branch.

Furthermore, you may ssume that all the commits in `S1`'s `master` branch come from `Q`, while the commits in the range `master..localpatches` are present only in `S1`.

Now, I also have a separate `git` repo `R2`, that is completely distinct from `R1`.  (By this I mean that `R1` and `R2` have no commits in common, they have different contributors, their associated work trees are completely different, etc.)

---

I would like to know the cleanest way to add a submodule `S2` to `R2` such that it is a replica of the `S1` submodule of `R1`.  In particular, (1) `S2`'s source repo should also be `Q`; (2) the `S2` should have two branches, `master` and `localpatches`; (3) the commits in the `master` (resp.`localpatches`) branches of `S1` and `S2` should be identical.

(Please correct me if I'm wrong, but the first of these requirements (namely, that `S2`'s source repo should be `Q`) argues against creating `S2` by just running `git submodule add <S1's URL>` in `R2`.)

(In case it matters, you may assume that the `R1` repo is obsolescent/defunct.  This means, in particular, that the issue of the future divergence between `S1` and `S2` is moot.)

Comment: Why not push you `localpatches` branch to `Q`, maybe rename it. And then add your submodule from there?

Comment: @ian: `Q` is owned by someone else, and they tend take months to consider, let alone accept, pull requests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### As onetime operation

1. create repo `R2` like normal
2. add submodule from Q `git submodule add <path to Q> S2`
3. when you cd into a submodule you can modify it `cd S2`
4. add `S1` in `R1` as remote `git remote add S1 <path to R1>/S1`
5. fetch `git fetch S1`
6. create a branch `git checkout -b localpatches S1/localpatches`
7. maybe remove S1 remote `git remote remove S1`

Now S2 has the same commits as S1. I showed this solution because you mentioned the link to R1/S1 is not important to you.

---

If you want to do this multiple times or want to share code between S1 and S2. It would be better to create a fork of Q. (could even be local) and add your fork as a remote to S1 and S2.